# Integration of Codeigniter_web_connector for quickbooks

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I was using the php dev kit ( https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php ).

I have integrated quickbooks with the palmer_sdk that was provided in the github.

currently i was working on a codeigniter based website.

There was a web connector for codeigniter in the SDK.

palmer_sdk\docs\example_codeigniter_web_connector

Please tell me how to configure the CODEIGNITER WEB CONNECTOR.

Comment: You didn't provide anywhere near enough information for anyone to answer your question. QuickBooks Online, or QuickBooks for Windows? If you've already integrated, then what's the problem? Isn't it already working? Exactly what issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: If you're using a version of QuickBooks that runs on Windows, then you are NOT using QuickBooks Online. QuickBooks Online is a website that you visit in a web browser. QuickBooks for Windows is a Windows application that runs on your computer. Two different things. Which are you using? Did you look at the CodeIgniter files? They are very, very basic standard CodeIgniter controllers and models.